# How to find numeric value before underscore(_) in php

Tags: javascript, php

good morning. I have a string like this:

```
$val="you-nick-name-2_yp52958122c7593";
```

now I want only 2 from this string before underscore, for this purpose I tried by substacting string and I did something like this:

```
$first = strrpos($val,"-");
echo substr($val,$first+1)."<br>";

//output

2_yp52958122c7593
```

but i want only 2 from this string and want to substract all string after _.
Thanks for help.

Comment: $tmpArray = explode( '_', $val ); echo substr($tmpArray,-1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newval = explode( '_', $val );
$data = explode( '-', $newval[0] );
$your_number = $data[3];
```

Comment: +1 sir , I was looking for a specific function but I like `explode' , it is working like charm....Thanks again   :)

Answer (score 2):

Using explode is not reliable. Regular expression is better.

```
$val="you-nick-name-2_yp52958122c7593";

$found = preg_match('/(\d+)_/', $val, $matches) ? $matches[1] : null;
```

It could be a problem if the $val string has more than one instance of 2_ (e.g. 'one 3_ two 4_).  Depends on what you want to achieve, you can still use preg_match and preg_match_all function to get the first match or all match.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous possibilities to do this..

### Way 1:

```
<?php
$val="you-nick-name-2_yp52958122c7593";
echo substr($val,strpos($val,'_')-1,1); //2
```

### Way 2:

```
<?php
$val="you-nick-name-2_yp52958122c7593";
echo array_pop(explode('-',strstr($val,'_',true))); //2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$val="you-nick-name-2_yp52958122c7593"; 
$first = strrpos($val,"-"); 
echo substr($val,$first+1,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

One more example:

```
$val="you-nick-name-24_yp52958122c7593";

$start = strrpos($val, '-') + 1;
$end = strpos($val, '_');

echo substr($val, $start , $end - $start );
```